# Image in jQuery Mobile Header

Tags: image, jquery-mobile, header

I am trying to add an image in the header of my jQuery Mobile based web page.

I want the image to be aligned to the right edge and using CSS for this purpose. But the results are not satisfactory.

**(Problem*)There is a big gap between the image and the edge and it is also not aligned with the header text.**

Here is the header code:

```
<header data-role='header'><h1>My App<img src="my_logo.png" alt="Low resolution logo"class="align-right"/></h1></header>
```

and here is the CSS code for class align-right:

```
.align-right{ 
    float:right; 
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

No need to add custom styling or such. Jquery-Mobile already has built-in solutions for this. Just add the class 'ui-btn-left' or 'ui-btn-right' to your image (as if it were a button) and you're all set.

```
<header data-role="header">
<h1>My App</h1>
<img src="my_logo.png" class="ui-btn-right" />
</header>
```

I know the question has been asked way before, but I figured this might help those who are still looking for solutions. Besides, the question wasn't set as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code example, you need a space between the `alt` attribute and the `class` attribute.

You have:

```
alt="Low resolution logo"class="align-right"
```

Should be:

```
alt="Low resolution logo" class="align-right"
```

Also, it is probably better to not have the `<img />` tag inside of your `<h1>` element.

Check out the docs for more information on custom headers: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<head>
    <style>
    body{ margin: 0; }
    .align-right{ float:right; margin-right: 0px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role='header'><h1>My App<img src="my_logo.png" alt="Low resolution logo"class="align-right"/></h1></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a link as a button in my Header, and I wanted the same results where the image would show in the top right corner. I also wanted additional attributes added to the image such as no text, no corners, no disc, etc. Using ui-btn-right alone broke those other attributes. The fix was to include both ui-btn and ui-btn-right to the class, as shown below:

```
<a href="#entriesPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">Options</a>
```